# why is `declare` valid in class properties but not in methods?

Tags: typescript

```
class A {
    // not valid on a method
    declare foo(): string;
    // but perfectly valid for a property
    declare bar: string;
}
```

What's the need for this to be as such? Can someone explain?

I just want to know why is this purposely forbidden, what's the limitation?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8CwAoa7oHpPQHYHsAXaANzBAEsATafXaMaAWwFNCALfK1DaKl0GABOLaADN8+ABQBKAFzQIhIRVwBzANw8M2aACMArsQAOLIWIGEQAT1Llq4-EIbRjQ-KaGFr29P0Ei+sIKSirqWigAvqhAA)

---

PS: It's not the same as:

```
class A {
    declare foo: () => string;
}
```

That's a **property** of a function type. It could be assigned to unlike a method. You could argue to add `readonly`, but we'd end up doing gymnastics.

Comment: ```declare``` used to tell ts that a variable or property exists, but it won't be created in the js code. It is used for class properties when you want to override a property from a parent class with a more specific type, but it is not used for class methods because methods need to be created in js code.

Comment: It is likely because methods are part of the class prototype and should have an implementation within the class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no explicit *need* for the restriction; it's just that the functionality you're looking for has never been implemented.  That is: it's a missing feature, not an intentional design.

Both [microsoft/TypeScript#38008](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38008) and [microsoft/TypeScript#48290](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48290) are open feature requests to allow the `declare` modifier on class methods.  If you want to see this implemented, it wouldn't hurt for you to go to these issues, give them a , and possibly comment with your use case (if it's more compelling than the ones already there).  Of course, it probably wouldn't *help* much either, since there are lots of open feature requests with more users asking for them... but if enough users follow suit then it has more of a chance of happening.

Until and unless it is implemented you will unfortunately need to work around it with various "gymnastics", which may or may not be sufficient for some use cases.

Comment: thank you for pointing out which issues are open for this.